# Go back to original start position without Quitting the application and opening it again

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio

purpose of the app really simple. Ask the user to enter a number and checks if the user number and randomly created number are the same. Until the user enters the correct number it goes on. Once the user enters correct number how can i change my random number so they can continue without quitting the application.Right now i have to quit once i find the correct number.And open it back again.
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        int number; //Global Variabble.

```
    public void clicked (View view ){
       EditText userinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userinput);
       String inputstring = userinput.getText().toString();
       if (inputstring == " "){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You havent entered anything",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    int inputint = Integer.parseInt(inputstring);

    if (inputint > number ){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No, too high",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (inputint < number){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No, too small",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Well Done! You Guessed it",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

        //System.out.println("Computer guessed number is: " + number);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Random r = new Random();
    number = r.nextInt(21);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Comment: put you random number logic in a method call it whenever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try random function like this

```
public void randomGenerator()
{
  Random r = new random
  number = r.nextInt(21) //put the int number creation in global
}
```

then call it at onCreate()

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    randomGenerator()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

also at the else statement

```
else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Well Done! You Guessed it",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        randomGenerator(); //random number after user get correct answer

    }
```

Comment: don't you think ,this logic requires the `number` field globally

Comment: yes i don't think about that. it must be created first in global

Answer (score 0):

you can put

`Random r = new Random();
number = r.nextInt(21); 
userinput.setText("");`

in a function, and call it when your intent is call for the first time (in the on create) and cal it again when the use has found the good number